# Kivy refresh image

Tags: python, kivy

I have an an image (kivy.uix.image.Image) instantiated with a source, but I change the source file's data.  How can I refresh the image to reflect the new data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard case, since the filename is used as key for caching.
You can clear all the cache, before changing the source:

```
from kivy.cache import Cache
Cache.remove('kv.image')
Cache.remove('kv.texture')
# then change the source of the image
```

It should be ok, but not efficient.

As qua-non said:

Also if you can use the development branch or wait for the 1.3 release. You can use the following functions to achieve just that ::

For the Image widget  Image.reload()

For the Core Image  Image.remove_from_cache()

Comment: In the development branch or the soon to be out 1.3 release. One can now use the following functions::

For the Image widget <kivy.uix.image.Image> [Image.reload()](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.image.html?highlight=image#kivy.uix.image.Image.reload)

For the Core Image <kivy.core.image.Image> [Image.remove_from_cache()](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.core.image.html?highlight=image#kivy.core.image.Image.remove_from_cache)