# Kivy reloading images

Tags: python, kivy

```
from kivy.core.image import Image as Imagec
self.tile.texture = Imagec("images/img1.png").texture
```

self.tile is an Image widget with no source mentioned.

I have scheduled the above mentioned command to run after 5 seconds after the program has started. But the image displayed does not change.

Question: How do I tell kivy that the texture of the image has changed and it needs to display the new texture on the screen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kivy refresh image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781345/kivy-refresh-image)

Comment: @sam-pyt I've tried .reload but it does not change anything